# How to open multiple split terminals for each npm script?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

I have like 5 npm scripts and each of them need their own terminal because they runned in watch mode and write something in console.

Here is the scripts:

```
"server-build-dev": "cd ts/backend && npx tsc -w && npm run server-lint",
"server-run-dev": "pm2 flush && pm2 start --only server --env development && pm2 logs",
"server-lint": "cd ts/backend && esw -w --ext .ts",
"client-build-dev": "cd ts/configs && npx webpack --config client.webpack.dev.js"
```

I prefer split terminals to see everything that is happennig.

What i'm hoping is to run all this scripts with one command. So if i type "npm run all-dev" vscode will open 5 split powersells for we where in each will be runned it's own script.

Is it possible? Or maybe there is another way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here : [Create multiple terminals and run commands in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621321/create-multiple-terminals-and-run-commands-in-vscode/60665510#60665510)

I just changed to use the `"workbench.action.terminal.splitInActiveWorkspace",` command instead of creating a new terminal for each command and it works nicely.  The demo gif doesn't really capture how quickly and fluidly it works.  Starting with no terminals open:

[image: open 4 split terminals]

---

You would not be running an master npm script like `npm run all-dev` but instead running a task that runs 4 npm scripts in 4 split terminals.

Same caveat as in the linked answer - interact with a terminal sometime after running the command - vscode freezes on me if I try to close the editors without opening one or opening a new one for example.  Hopefully that bug will be fixed.  Just hit the `+` button first before you start deleting these split terminals and it never freezes on me.